# Performance issues in datagridview

Tags: asp.net, performance, datagridview

I have been asked a question that "how performance can be optimized when using a datagridview in case when table contains millions of rows"? Please answer it.

Comment: Does the query contain select *? If so removing that can be a start. Also is paging being used?

Comment: Use pagination with Skip and Take.

Answer (score 0):

Performance issues in web page can be divided into 3 categories and it needs to be analysed what part of code is creating the bottleneck using various mechanism like logging, tracing etc.

3 categories are

1. Client  side
2. Web Server
3. DB

Client

1. You can use paging so that html rendered is less
2. You should you plain html controls inside gridview which do not have server events
3. You can control naming of the controls used in the page, if longer the names of controls more number of bytes rendered on client side

Server
1. Caching
2. Use custom pagination, then you can set enabledviewstate= false
3. Try to minimize the viewstate

DB
Fine tuning the queries using indexes, analyzing the cost of the query and using appropriate remedies. Partioning tables

Every area requires a specific focus and is driven by issues faced in performance.